# Python: Unable to get the module from same folder

Tags: python, machine-learning

i have a folder pre_trained_models containing files

- merge_model.py
- VG16.py
- VG19.py
- **init**.py

**After running merge_model.py file, i am getting error:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge_model.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pre_trained_models.VG16 import vg_16_get_features
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pre_trained_models'
```

**merge_models is importing files as follows**:

```
    from pre_trained_models.VG16 import vg_16_get_features
from pre_trained_models.VG19 import vg_19_get_features
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions :

1) If you need to make `pre_trained_models` folder as a python package :

you need to rename the **init.py** to **__init__.py**

Like this Python will recognize the folder as a package

And then you should be able to import in the way you suggest :

```
from pre_trained_models.VG16 import vg_16_get_features
```

2) Import directly from another module in the same folder
For this you do not have to specify "pre_trained_models" since merge_model.py is in the same folder just do so :

```
from VG16 import vg_16_get_features
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **merge_model.py** is inside the **pre_trained_models** and so the **VG16.py** and **VG19.py**

It should be

```
from VG16 import vg_16_get_features
```